# How to do onething after another in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I find myself wanting to do this, which feels like it ought to be wrong.

```
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.service.getFirstValue().subscribe((response: firstValueType) => {
      this.firstValue = response;
      this.service.getSecondValue(this.firstValue).subscribe((response: secondValueType) => {
        this.secondValue = response;
        this.isLoading = false
      });
    });
```

What are you *supposed* to do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use switchMap. Also embedded subscribe is bad practice, supposed to be avoided

```
this.isLoading = true;
this.service
.getFirstValue()
.pipe(
    switchMap(response => {
        this.firstValue = response;
        return this.service.getSecondValue(this.firstValue);
    })
)
.subscribe(response => {
    this.secondValue = response;
    this.isLoading = false;
});
```

PS fix the code, subscribe should be outside of pipe

Comment: This doesn't work because `switchMap` returns an `OperatorFunction` that does not have a `subscribe` method.

Comment: I think there is a typo in this response. The `subscribe` call should be outside the `pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I figured out works fine for me in my project was using the following parts of rxjs:

- [ConnectableObservable](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ConnectableObservable)
- [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)
- [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)

```js
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { publishReplay, tap, switchMapTo } = rxjs.operators;

// Simulates your service.getFirstValue, ...
const source1$$ = new Subject();
const source2$$ = new Subject();
const source3$$ = new Subject();

// Publish and Replay the last value to be able to connect (make it hot) and always get the lates value
const source1$ = source1$$.pipe(publishReplay(1));
const source2$ = source2$$.pipe(publishReplay(1));
const source3$ = source3$$.pipe(publishReplay(1));

// Connect to make the observable hot
source1$.connect()
source2$.connect()
source3$.connect()

source1$.pipe(
  tap(v => console.log('tap source1$: ', v)),
  switchMapTo(source2$),
  tap(v => console.log('tap source2$: ', v)),
  switchMapTo(source3$),
  tap(v => console.log('tap source3$: ', v))
).subscribe()

source3$$.next('value 1');
source2$$.next('value 2');
source1$$.next('value 3');
source2$$.next('value 4');
source2$$.next('value 5');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure if this fits your exactly requirements. But imo this is a at least close szenario like yours. If you want give me feedback and I try to adapt :)

Answer (score 0):

Nested `subscribe` should be avoided.

In this case I would go like this

```
this.isLoading = true;
this.service.getFirstValue().pipe(
  // this tap is necessary only if you use this.firstValue somewhere else in the code
  // otherwise you can skip it and go directly to concatMap
  tap((response_1: firstValueType) => this.firstValue = response_1),
  // concatMap is usually the preferred operator to use when concatenating http calls
  // read the article I have linked below
  concatMap(response_1 => this.service.getSecondValue(response_1)),
  tap(response_2 => {
    this.secondValue = response_2;
    this.isLoading = false;
  })
).subscribe()
```

You can get some more inspiration on how to deal with http calls and rxJs [reading this article.](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a)