# Using RxJS to remove nested callbacks when things must be done in sequence

Tags: rxjs

I need to do one HTTP request after another, but the second one can't start until after the first one has finished because the second needs as a parameter a value returned from the first.

Here it is with a nested callback which is great because it works and it's fairly clear from reading the code what is happening.

```
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.firstService.get(this.id)
      .subscribe((response: FirstReturnType) => {
        this.firstThing = response;

        this.secondService.get(this.firstThing.secondId)
          .subscribe(
            (response: SecondReturnType) => {
              this.secondThing = response;
              this.isLoading = false;
            }
      }
```

The claim I see people making is that nested callbacks are bad and that one should use RxJS to make it better.

However, nobody making these claims has been able to produce a working example. Can you?

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Comment: Maybe [this article can give some inspiration](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) on how to use RxJs with http

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do onething after another in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65740879/how-to-do-onething-after-another-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 2):

#### Your Code Re-written

Here is some code that has a 1-1 correspondence with your code, but it is flattened

```js
this.isLoading = true;
this.firstService.get(this.id).pipe(
  mergeMap((response: FirstReturnType) => {
    this.firstThing = response;
    return this.secondService.get(response.secondId);
  })
).subscribe((response: SecondReturnType) => {
  this.secondThing = response;
  this.isLoading = false;
});
```

What this gets right: you're using a higher-order observable operator to map a value emitted by one observable into a new observable that you subscribe to. In this case, mergeMap is subscribing for you and getting rid of your nesting.

---

#### For Your Consideration

Consider this. The following is about as clean looking at six service calls (each giving some value to the next one) in a row can get if you're not using a higher-order operator:

```js
this.firstService.getThing("First").subscribe(result1 => {
  this.secondService.getThing(result1.value).subscribe(result2 => {
    this.thirdService.getThing(result2.value).subscribe(result3 => {
      this.fourthService.getThing(result3.value).subscribe(result4 => {
        this.fifthService.getThing(result4.value).subscribe(result5 => {
          this.sixthService.getThing(result5.value).subscribe(result6 => {
            console.log("Result Six is: " + result6.value);
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here's the exact same thing with mergeMap:

```js
this.firstService.getThing("First").pipe(
  mergeMap(result1 => this.secondService.getThing(result1.value)),
  mergeMap(result2 => this.thirdService.getThing(result2.value)),
  mergeMap(result3 => this.fourthService.getThing(result3.value)),
  mergeMap(result4 => this.fifthService.getThing(result4.value)),
  mergeMap(result5 => this.sixthService.getThing(result5.value)),
).subscribe(result6 => {
  console.log("Result Six is: " + result6.value);
});
```

If that's not enough to convince you, you can lean a little bit more into some functional programming to make this even cleaner (without repetitively naming each result)

```js
const passValueToService = service => result => service.getThing(result.value);

passValueToService(this.firstService)("First").pipe(
  mergeMap(passValueToService(this.secondService)),
  mergeMap(passValueToService(this.thirdService)),
  mergeMap(passValueToService(this.fourthService)),
  mergeMap(passValueToService(this.fifthService)),
  mergeMap(passValueToService(this.sixthService)),
).subscribe(finalResult => {
  console.log("Result Six is: " + finalResult.value);
});
```

Or why not lean EVEN harder and keep our list of services in an array?

```js
const [firstS, ...restS] = [this.firstService, this.secondService, this.thirdService, this.fourthService, this.fifthService, this.sixthService];

const passValueToService = service => result => service.getThing(result.value);

passValueToService(firstS)("first").pipe(
  ...restS.map(service => mergeMap(passValueToService(service)))
).subscribe(finalResult => {
  console.log("Result Six is: " + finalResult.value);
});
```

None of these simplifications are very easily done while nesting subscribe calls. But with the help of some functional currying (and the handy RxJS `pipe` to compose with), you can begin to see that your options expand dramatically.

## Understanding `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, & `switchMap`

#### The Setup

We'll have 3 helper functions as described here:

```js
/****
 * Operator: intervalArray
 * -----------------------
 * Takes arrays emitted by the source and spaces out their
 * values by the given interval time in milliseconds
 ****/
function intervalArray<T>(intervalTime = 1000): OperatorFunction<T[], T> {
  return s => s.pipe(
    concatMap((v: T[]) => concat(
      ...v.map((value: T) => EMPTY.pipe(
        delay(intervalTime),
        startWith(value)
      ))
    ))
  );
}

/****
 * Emit 1, 2, 3, then complete: each 0.5 seconds apart
 ****/
function n123Stream(): Observable<number> {
  return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
    intervalArray(500)
  );
}

/****
 * maps:
 *   1 => 10, 11, 12, then complete: each 1 second apart 
 *   2 => 20, 21, 22, then complete: each 1 second apart
 *   3 => 30, 31, 32, then complete: each 1 second apart
 ****/
function numberToStream(num): Observable<number>{
  return of([num*10, num*10+1, num*10+2]).pipe(
    intervalArray(1000)
  );
}
```

The above mapping function (`numberToStream`), takes care of the **map** part of `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, and `switchMap`

#### Subscribing to each operator

The following three snippits of code will all have different outputs:

```js
n123Stream().pipe(
  concatMap(numberToStream)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```js
n123Stream().pipe(
  mergeMap(numberToStream)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```js
n123Stream().pipe(
  switchMap(numberToStream)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

If you want to run these back-to-back:

```js
concat(
  ...[concatMap, mergeMap, switchMap].map(
    op => n123Stream().pipe(
      op(numberToStream),
      startWith(`${op.name}: `)
    )
  )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### concatMap:

`concatMap` will not subscribe to the second inner observable until the first one is complete. That means that the number 13 will be emitted before the second observable (starting with the number 20) will be subscribed to.

The output:

```html
10 11 12 20 21 22 30 31 32
```

All the 10s are before the 20s and all the 20s are before the 30s

#### mergeMap:

`mergeMap` will subscribe to the second observable the moment the second value arrives and then to the third observable the moment the third value arrives. It doesn't care about the order of output or anything like that.

The output

```html
10 20 11 30 21 12 31 22 32
```

The 10s are earlier because they started earlier and the 30s are later because they start later, but there's some interleaving in the middle.

#### switchMap

`switchMap` will subscribe to the first observable the moment the first value arrives. It will unsubscribe to the first observable and subscribe to the second observable the moment the second value arrives (and so on).

The output

```html
10 20 30 31 32
```

Only the final observable ran to completion in this case. The first two only had time to emit their first value before being unsubscribed. Just like concatMap, there is no interleaving and only one inner observable is running at a time, but some emissions are effectively dropped.

Comment: I think `concatMap` is a better operator than `mergeMap` with http

Comment: If the service call emits once and completes, then it doesn't matter. Otherwise, yeah, `concatMap` or `switchMap` might be better depending on the type of HTTP traffic. But a nested subscribe is most closely modeled by a `mergeMap`. Both subscribe upon emission from the source and don't manage 'inner' subscriptions further.

Comment: My comment about `concatMap` as the usually right operator for http calls derives from my experience and from a comment of Ben Lesh, the main contributor of rxjs, which you can listen at the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsku0F4lU3A&list=PLJBWPTwg7fuNKFg5BRXKTvDrEi-45YzSE&index=1&t=46s). The preference for `concatMap` is stronger with POST/PUT calls, since it ensures you receive the response from each call before doing anything, which helps avoiding multiple POST/PUT in fly at the same time.

Comment: @Picci Yup. Also switchMap is often preferable with GET calls as you're often only interested in the freshest data. I'll repeat, however, that If the service call emits once and completes, then it doesn't matter. Those considerations are not at play.

Comment: I thought `mergeMap` make things come out in the order they complete whereas here I _must_ wait for the first to complete in orer to use it's output as input to the second. The page for `mergeMap` says: _If only one inner subscription should be active at a time, try `switchMap`_.
This suggests that this cannot work.

Comment: This seems to work, but I don't understand why it makes things come out in sequence.

Comment: mergeMap takes every value **from the source**, maps/projects it to an observable using the given callback function (in this case, a lambda function), and subscribes to that mapped/projected observable. If your source emits 5 values, you'll subscribe to 5 projected obervables without any guarantee on order. If your case, your source is just emitting one value, so the **merge** part of `mergeMap` never comes into play.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough I added a blurb describing the difference between `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, and `switchMap` with some code that I encourage you to run and mess with a bit so you can understand what is happening under the hood (so to speak)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switchMap`.

```js
this.firstService.get(this.id)
  .pipe(
    tap((response: FirstReturnType) => this.firstThing = response),
    switchMap((response: FirstReturnType) => this.secondService.get(response.secondId)),
    tap((response: SecondReturnType) => {
      this.secondThing = response;
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  ).subscribe();
```

Comment: Which? Surely they do different things so only one of them can be correct? And why? And why not `mergeMap`? I _can_ use nested callbacks -- and I still think they're the best solution.

Comment: I've implemented this and it doesn't work: inside the `switchMapTo` when it dereferences the value assigned by the first `tap` it gets `undefined`. Adding log messages shows that the `switchMapTo` starts _before_ the `tap` has finished.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough `switchMap` and `switchMapTo` both do the same thing, they switch to a new observable. The difference is that `switchMapTo` takes an observable as parameter while `switchMap` takes a callback which must return an observable. If you need the emitted value for your second stream, `switchMap` is the way to go. It gets `undefined` because it's a bad idea to use a class property assigned with an emitted value instead of directly using the value from the stream itself. I have updated my answer.